# ConcurrentHashMap update of multiple entries

Tags: java, concurrency, concurrenthashmap

i have a situation that in ConcurrentHashMap im storing some properties like ip address and port or penalty fee and code - 2 or more entries that are connected to each other.

Now i want to update those 2 entries atomically to avoid reading incorrect pairs.

So now im thinking about it and dont know simple sollution.

I could wrap get/put methods with ReadWriteLock blocks but that feels wrong :) I'm not using ConcurrentHashMap to write additional locks.

Other option is to merge those properties into one. Right now i'm leaning towards that option.

Other option is to have version in value object but then i need to check it every time and i dont want to do it :)

Is there some other sollution to that problem ?

Regards

Comment: I think the easiest solution would be the option with merging those properties. If you create an immutable object then you're guaranteed that both values are "from the same version".

Comment: *Other option is to merge those properties into one. Right now i'm leaning towards that option.* would be my suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't atomically update multiple entries. You have two options:

- Use a simple `HashMap` with external synchronization.
- Use a different type for the `Map` values, which goes the pair of items that must be considered together.

Comment: The second option is better, because the first will cost you some overhead when you use your map.

Answer (score 1):

I think, You can use different way, without `ConcurrentHashMap.`

If you want to add somethink like the priority of your operations. e.g.: update operations in higher then get operations, You can use `PriorityBlockingQueue`, and e.g..:`HashSet` to storing objects without repetition. Then You are sure Your actual properties is the newest one.

Comment: That is another option but i dont want to add another queue with operation to perform on my Map.